# The controller function is not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm learning AngularJs and i complete some courses in internet i know what is module, controller, service, i know some basics directives, and i found in internet a basic AngularJs video tutorial, i'm doing all like in this video but can't understand why it's not work.
Here is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);


app.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.todos = [
  {
   text: "Learn AngularJs"
  },
  {
   text: "Build App"
  }
 ];

 $scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText});
 };
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
 <title>todo</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/underscore-master/underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script src="todo.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="todoCtrl">
  <h2>Total todos: {{todos.length}}</h2>
  <ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="text" ng-model="todoText">
  <button class="btn" ng-click="addTodo()"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i></button>
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

It should insert new text in my array, but when i'm clikcking on the button nothing happens, and no error in console, i realy can't understand why?

Comment: The title of your question should be more specific

Comment: could you please use plunker or codepen

Answer (score 3):

The ng-click event is out of the controller's scope. The quick answer is to move `ng-controller="todoCtrl"` to an enclosing/outer element, which is `body` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Move the ng-controller attribute to the `<body>` - so that it incorporates the form and the ng-click event. For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.todos = [
  {
   text: "Learn AngularJs"
  },
  {
   text: "Build App"
  }
 ];

 $scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText});
 };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<body ng-controller="todoCtrl">
 <div>
  <h2>Total todos: {{todos.length}}</h2>
  <ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="text" ng-model="todoText">
  <button class="btn" ng-click="addTodo()"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i></button>
 </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `model` and `functions` should be in scope to be used, so you need to have `addTodo` function called within `todoCtrl` scope. Just add a wrapper and have the controller there.

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);


app.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.todos = [
  {
   text: "Learn AngularJs"
  },
  {
   text: "Build App"
  }
 ];

 $scope.addTodo = function() {
  $scope.todos.push({text: $scope.todoText});
 };
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
 <title>todo</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/underscore-master/underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script src="todo.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="todoCtrl" class="wrapper">
    <div>
  <h2>Total todos: {{todos.length}}</h2>
  <ul class="unstyled">
   <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <form class="form-horizontal">
  <input type="text" ng-model="todoText">
  <button class="btn" ng-click="addTodo()"><i class="icon-plus">Add</i></button>
 </form>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is difference between @Donal and your answer?

Comment: Donal is adding controller to body, there would be problem If OP has to add more controllers to different sections.

Comment: you just added a div wrapper.that doesn't make more sense to me..the same thing has covered by Donal & chris answer..

Comment: I already answered your question in previous comment.. what if OP has to add more controllers.. unnecessarily they would become nested and can cause issues.So its always better practice to have controllers as far as scope is needed.. does that make sense now

Comment: you are correct Vinayak but as OP's current question, the answer part is already given..you are giving an extras which are not adding that much weight in your answer..

Comment: OH MY GOD, i'm so sorry guys, what a stupid situation, i should be more attentive, sorry, and thanx everyone)